# Counting number of sequences in time series

Tags: python, statistics, data-science

I have binary data containing 1's and 0's.
I want to count how many different sequences there are in the data and how many times each occurs using python.

If I have for example `[1011111010000010]`
The first sequence should start from 1 and end before we have 1 again but after the 0's.

Example: `[10], [111110] ,[100000] , [10]`

Here is what I use to find the maximum sequence of 0's or 1's:

```
def max_seq(array, len):

   count = 0
   result = 0

   for i in range(len(0, len)):

      if(array[i] == 0):
         count += 1
         result = max(result, count)
      else:
         count = 0

   return result
```

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Should `10101` gives `10, 10 ,1` or just `10, 10` ?

Comment: I am not a student and do not know why you assume it's some type of homework. I can't think of any code that can make this, the best I could do is to find the max sequence of 1's in the array I have. In my search in the forums, I could not find a solution where the start and the end of the sequences are as I mentioned.

Comment: Always share your tries, no matter th size of them. I don't assume your a student, see it as `(home)work`

Comment: Edit your post to add code, not in the comments ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest an easy regex like `'(1+0*)'` to find all the series in the content, to get the occurence count, you can use a `Counter`

```
import re
from collections import Counter

parts = re.findall('(1+0*)', '1011111010000010')
print(parts)  # ['10', '111110', '100000', '10']

parts = Counter(re.findall('(1+0*)', '1011111010000010'))
print(parts)  # {'10': 2, '111110': 1, '100000': 1}


parts = Counter(re.findall('(1+0*)', '1011010011010010110010110010101'))
print(parts)  # {'10': 3, '110': 2, '100': 2, '1100': 1, '1': 1}
```

Comment: Is that going to work with a series or array of 3000 - 10 000 observations?

Comment: @Troublesome why don't you try if you have the data ? Is 10000 the length of the string ? I'd yes

Comment: It's a time-series data, not a string.